# How to open specific collapsible panel inside bootstrap modal by clicking in link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to make a login/registration modal, but i can not create links to appropriate panels in this modal.

buttons:

```
<div class="btn-group">
<button data-toggle="dropdown" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle activation-menu-cta" aria-expanded="false">Btn <span class="caret"></span></button>
<ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right-fix">
    <li><a id="panelOne" type="btn" data-toggle="modal" href="#myModal">panel one</a></li>
    <li><a id="panelTwo" type="btn" data-toggle="modal" href="#myModal">panel two</a></li>
</ul>
```

modal:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="panel-group" id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingOne">
                         <h4 class="panel-title">
                            <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
                                panel one
                            </a>
                        </h4>
                    </div>
                    <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne">
                        <div class="panel-body">text 1</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingTwo">
                         <h4 class="panel-title">
                            <a class="collapsed" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
                                panel two
                            </a>
                        </h4>
                    </div>
                    <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingTwo">
                        <div class="panel-body">text 2</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/gmoefesr/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `data-toggle="modal"` attribute from both of your buttons, add `open-modal` class, and set [**`.modal('show')`** method](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-methods) in the *script* section.

You should also remove `type="btn"` as it's not a proper attribute for anchors.

Use bootstrap modal [**`X.bs.modal`**](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-events) event to keep `collapse` animations visible when modal opens.

HTML:

```
<li><a class="open-modal" href="#collapseOne">panel one</a></li>
<li><a class="open-modal" href="#collapseTwo">panel two</a></li>
```

JS:

```
var panelTarget;
$('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function(){
    $(panelTarget).collapse('show');
});

$('.open-modal').click(function(){
    panelTarget = $(this).attr('href');
    $('.collapse.in').collapse('hide');
    $('#myModal').modal('show');
});
```

[**JSFiddle demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/zbzj7uzg/)

Answer (score 2):

This may help you.

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.collapse').collapse();
        $('#panelOne').click(function () {
            $('#collapseOne').collapse('show');
            $('#collapseTwo').collapse('hide');
        });
        $('#panelTwo').click(function () {
            $('#collapseTwo').collapse('show');
            $('#collapseOne').collapse('hide');
        });
    });
```

http://jsbin.com/ropamajola/1/

Comment: it's close. if I use happy day scenario  it's perfect:)

Comment: edit: It's close. If I use happy day scenario  it's perfect:) but if I collapse panel in open modal, close the modal and repeat the process, then solution isn't work.  I noticed that when panel collapse, class is changed from collapse to collapsing for a while.  https://jsfiddle.net/gmoefesr/2/